# nginx access log and yandex search engine

Tags: nginx

I've seen some strange logs in nginx access log. I've move /admin page to /adminSecretUrl, my website can only be access via https (except /robots.txt).

`95.221.204.97 - - [11/Sep/2016:17:09:12 +0200] "GET /adminSecretUrl HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=[...]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"`

How yandex search engine know this url? Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

There must be a link to it somewhere, for example your xml sitemap, which tends to be at http://example.com/sitemap.xml

Changing the URL is called "security by obscurity", and is one of the weakest forms of security. Your website should be secure enough that if the admin URL is published no-one can get into the website anyway. To do this take the usual precautions, software and OS patched, firewall only allowing standard ports, and ideally two factor authentication.

You can also block specific user agents, though given this is trivial to change I don't see any benefit.

Comment: I've installed an admin fake login screen, and move real admin to other destination.

I'm developing with django, and have installed no sitemap.xml. Furthermore, only ip from limited countries have access to my website with nginx HttpGeoipModule. (That's why there is a 444 response in the log). If external services cannot get this url directly from my website, is this possible that, for example, a browser extension send all visited urls to some servers?

Comment: Double check the sitemap xml / xml.gz, and your site may actually link to the admin screen somewhere. Search engines aren't magic and won't randomly try every possible path on the server, it will have gotten it from somewhere. Really, I think this whole question is a non-issue. Ensure you have sufficient security and don't worry about who's crawling which pages on your website.

Comment: Yandex has looked for sitemap file, only 444 response. I've changed admin url some days ago. If I suppose that yandex hasn't been able to find sitemap like files, I just want to known how yandex has proceeded to known those urls (without magics). To be sure, I've disable firefox WOT extension, which knows all links I visit.

Comment: Like I said, crawlers aren't magic, it's picking it up somewhere. If you post your website URL you might get more help. Try grep'ing your web source tree or crawling your website yourself with a tool. I doubt anyone can tell you any more without more information.

Comment: Thanks. I've used httrack to crawl my website, and have found nothing related to admin page. I really thing that the problem was WOT which collects: «Browsing usage, including visited web pages, clickstream data or web address accessed;» (from [wot privacy policy](https://www.mywot.com/en/privacy/privacy_policy)) and perhaps send it to yandex (since we can see `wot.partner = "yandex";` in wot js code file). Now, in logs, yandex try to fetch old admin secret urls... Not the new one since I changed it and disabled wot.